# How to resize image file on Xamarin.forms. (+ writeableBitmap package can't be added)

Tags: xamarin

I'm making iOS and Android app using with Xamarin.forms. (PCL project)

I need to resize my image file from 'MediaFile class' that is returned from 'CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync ()'.

What's your best way to do it?

and I have searched long time and noticed that many people uses 'writeableBitmap'. 
But this 'writeableBitmap' nuget package can not be added because Xamarin platform is updated?

Answer (score 1):

I got great answer from here.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/199212#Comment_199212

It's using DependencyService and it works beautifully.

After applied DependencyService, I got a question.

In my thinking, image file is not dependent so why don't we process it just in 'forms' using with SOME image process library in .net? (I'm not a .net developer but I believe that there is many library to process image file)
I suspect that we should have done because we want to use built-in image processing library(like UIKit) so that we could avoid adding new one?

Am I correct?

Comment: Could you add the code here? Because the linked content can disappear ...